# GnuPG with IDEA support

Tags: encryption, command-line, gnupg

I'm attempting to "integrate" support for the IDEA cipher into my current system that uses the GnuPG command-line interface for encrypting/decrypting data files sent between my company and our partners.  I've read all of the instructions I can find online for various ways to get this set up, and I'm still unable to get the IDEA cipher to load properly.

First, my configuration: I'm using Windows 7 (64-bit) Professional and GnuPG 2.0.17.  The `--version` lists as follows:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.0.17 (Gpg4win 2.1.0)
libgcrypt 1.4.6
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA
Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH, CAMELLIA128,
        CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

The command-line executable is actually located on a network share (**`\\<SERVERNAME>\<ShareName>\GnuPG\gpg.exe`**), which generally works perfectly for everything I have to encrypt/decrypt ***EXCEPT*** when I run into files encrypted using the IDEA cipher.  I get the following message when it tries:

```
gpg: cipher algorithm 1 (IDEA) is unknown or disabled
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG key, ID C4186BB7, created 2003-05-14
      "<keyname@domain.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Invalid cipher algorithm
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

So, I started Googling everything I could find.  I've downloaded the **`idea.dll`** library (after digging through all sorts of junk trying to find it) and placed it in the `\\<SERVERNAME>\<ShareName>\GnuPG\lib` directory, as instructed.

Most of the resources I can find talk about adding the line `load-extension lib\idea` to the **`gpg.conf`** file located in **`C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/gnupg`**.  This doesn't work, as I still get the same results to the `--version` command (no IDEA cipher listed in the supported algorithms).  I've also tried explicitly using the full path to the library instead of just the "shortcut" like this: `load-extension "\\<SERVERNAME>\<ShareName>\GnuPG\lib\idea.dll"`, but no luck.

Another suggestion is to add the `load-extension` switch to the actual command-line like this:

`\\<SERVERNAME>\<ShareName>\GnuPG\gpg.exe --load-extension idea`

I've tried multiple variations of this option as well, including using the full file name, the full path and file name, etc., but I still can't get the IDEA cipher to load.  I've tried putting the **`idea.dll`** in the GnuPG Home directory (**`C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/gnupg`**) and trying to get GnuPG to load it from that location with all of the same suggestions as listed above.

The **`idea.dll`** file I have doesn't have any version information listed in the Properties dialog, but it's modification date is listed as 20 September 2002.  Any suggestions on something I may have overlooked here?

**EDIT 1:** I'd eventually like to move away from doing my encryption/decryption via command-line and migrate my application to use the BouncyCastle API, as I believe the IDEA cipher is "built-in" over there.  Unfortunately, though, I'm having issues getting that working as well (see my [SO question on the problems I'm facing with BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616176/replacing-gnupg-command-line-with-bouncy-castle-in-net-application-vb)).

**EDIT 2:** One other thing to note is that all of the testing I've done above has been from a basic (elevated) command prompt - completely outside of my actual application - so that I can eliminate that as a potential cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm unsure about the details, but there was an issue with loading `.dll` files from a network share which is prevented sometimes for security reasons. [I found a forum post with some discussion](http://communities.bentley.com/products/programming/microstation_programming/f/343173/t/91973) in a brief survey, but am not sure whether this actually is the problem you're observing. Try loading it from a local folder to verify the issue, anyway.

Comment: **@JensErat -** Thank you for the link, and for your insight.  As I stated above, I've tried moving the **`idea.dll`** into the GnuPG Home directory on my local machine and trying to load it from there with no success.  Based on your comment, I even tried copying the entire application directory structure to a local folder (**`C:\GnuPG`**), and running everything from there, but it still won't load the IDEA cipher.  One thing I thought of was making sure that the **`idea.dll`** file was "unblocked" from the Properties dialog, but that didn't help either.  This is really getting frustrating.

Comment: From what I read, you might have to compile the .dll file on your own. Are you sure it is a library compiled for GnuPG, and for the same architecture you're using? Just using some arbitrary compiled code you found somewhere for _trusted operations_ seems like a very bad thing to do generally.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it's "legit", although it's been a long time since I actually downloaded it.  I had run across this issue a few years ago and did a bunch of research, but wasn't able to get it working.  At that time, though, I only had one file that was using IDEA, and I decided to just manually decrypt it (my Windows PGP Desktop application seems to have no problems with IDEA) instead of trying to automate it.  Now I'm getting more files with this cipher (I don't know why), so I'm having to revisit this whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I kept digging around and even cross-posted my question on the Spiceworks community site.  One of the things I found - but had basically ignored, as I didn't see the relevance at the time - was a [thread in the GnuPG mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2012-June/044809.html).  However, one of the other users over on Spiceworks pointed it out to me again, so I gave it another read.  I'm basically reposting what I posted over on that site as a reference for anyone else who might run into this issue.

Here's what Werner Koch said in his message on that mailing list:

> Nope.  GnuPG-2 does not support loading of extensions.  the option is a dummy option.  The reason for this is that crypto operations are done by Libgcrypt and not by gpg.exe.
>
> The next version of Libgcrypt will support IDEA and thus GnuPG 2.1 will be able to decrypt old (i.e. PGP 2) files, directly.  However, using IDEA is not a good idea, we have far better algorithms for ages.

...and the response from the person asking the question was:

> When I have to make use of "idea.dll" so that I can decrypt messages
> that  were encrypted with it, I then use Gpg 1.4.x, and I have it in
> an altogether  separate folder from the real installation of Gpg
> 2.0.x. I could not agree  with you more in regard to its comparatively inferior algorithms, but that  does not preclude my needing it from
> time to time.
>
> Is there any reason I should not place it in the same folder as the
> gpg.exe  version 1.4.x and then make reference to it there? Thanks.

Based on these comments, I figured that, since I'm using GnuPG v2.0.17, maybe I need to try to find an older version of GnuPG (from the 1.4.x family) I can use.  I found and downloaded the source code for 1.4.20, downloaded MnGW/MSYS and tried to compile it.  Unfortunately, I had problems getting it to compile, and errors kept popping up in the process.

Then, I just happened to be looking at a Windows Explorer window to check a path for some of the files I was working with, and I noticed another directory that contained the **`gpg.exe`** file.  I fired up a command prompt and just tried to run a `--version` check on it, and I got this:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.9
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>;
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
**gpg: LoadLibrary failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

gpg: invalid module `c:\\lib\\gnupg\lib/idea': The specified module could not be
 found.**

Cipher: 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

***HOLY CRAP!***  It's version **1.4.9**, and this time it actually appears that it's at least *TRYING* to load the IDEA library!

So, I tried again, but this time I used the `--load-extension` switch:

```
C:\gnu\gnupg\gpg --load-extension C:\GnuPG\lib\idea.dll --version
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.9
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>;
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: **IDEA**, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

***HOLY CRAP AGAIN!***  There's the IDEA cipher this time!

So, now comes the *real* test - I tried my command line to decrypt the file using this older executable:

```
C:\GNU\GnuPG\gpg.exe --load-extension C:\GnuPG\lib\idea.dll --batch --passphrase <password> --output "C:\Testing\decrypted.txt" --decrypt "C:\Testing\encrypted.pgp"
```

Executing this now gives me the following output:

```
gpg: WARNING: cipher algorithm IDEA not found in recipient preferences
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID C4186BB7, created 2003-05-14
      "<keyname@domain.com>"
```

I looked, and sure enough, the decrypted file ***IS THERE!*** Even though I got the warning about the IDEA cipher algorithm, it still decrypted the file normally, and put it out exactly as expected!

I guess the answer here is that you can't use GnuPG v2.0.x to decrypt files encrypted using the IDEA cipher at all.  It would seem that you have to drop back to a previous version of GnuPG in order to even load the library.  Thanks for your help.  I think I can finally put together a working command-line solution now.  Maybe one day I'll actually finish working on the BouncyCastle API implementation, but for now I'm just happy to get the thing working. (*doing my happy dance*)

**EDIT:** So, for my "final" (but definitely not perfect) solution, I've got my application attempting to decrypt the file via the 2.0 version, then, if that fails (the decrypted file doesn't exist), try to decrypt using the 1.4 version with the IDEA cipher loaded. Through all of my testing so far, it seems that this works exactly as expected, and my IDEA-encrypted files are being decrypted normally.  I should probably build something that actually reads the standard output from the command line to make the determination whether or not to try again with 1.4, but this looks like it's going to work for my purposes until I can figure out BouncyCastle.